# fs error or hardware?

Tags: filesystems, hardware

TL;DR - is this error due to file system issue or hardware issue (card or laptop)

So my Raspberry Pi wasn't responding when I got home from work just now.  Bad news, since it is DHCP, DNS, etc. for my LAN at home.

Get it over to the TV, plug it in, file system errors.  Apparently it rebooted for some reason, and it can't mount the root fs due to errors.

No problem, power it off, grab the card out, put it in my laptop thinking I'll just run a `fsck.ext4` and be happy...

The laptop doesn't see any partitions.  When I check `/var/log/syslog` I see mmc stuff being loaded, but then what appears to be an error relating to one of the actual block devices, and then nothing.

So...

Is this kernel error due to file system error that I know about, and my only solution is to just re-image the card?

Or is this a hardware error and the driver isn't loading properly for my device, and I need to find other hardware to use to fix the known file system error?

Or is this a hardware error and my card is dead, the fs error on the pi was just weirdness due to HW failure, and I need a new card and to of course put a new image on it?

Laptop is an old Acer running Mint 19 kernel 4.15.x

Thanks!

Interesting bits from `/var/log/syslog` -

```
Aug 28 21:31:42 darkstar kernel: [  607.172855] mmc0: Tuning timeout, falling back to fixed sampling clock
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180830] mmc0: Timeout waiting for hardware interrupt.
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180840] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180877] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x001080c8 | Version:  0x00001502
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180884] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180891] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x076f4f80 | Trn mode: 0x0000003b
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180899] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x1fff0000 | Host ctl: 0x0000001f
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180906] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180913] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180920] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180927] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180934] mmc0: sdhci: AC12 err:  0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180941] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x176ec8b0 | Caps_1:   0x03002177
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180948] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x0000123a | Max curr: 0x00000000
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180955] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0x00000900
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180962] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000900 | Resp[3]:  0x00000900
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180967] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000804b
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180976] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000001 | ADMA Ptr: 0x000000014ee69204
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.180979] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181054] mmc0: Unexpected interrupt 0x04000000.
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181058] mmc0: sdhci: ============ SDHCI REGISTER DUMP ===========
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181065] mmc0: sdhci: Sys addr:  0x00000000 | Version:  0x00001502
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181072] mmc0: sdhci: Blk size:  0x00007200 | Blk cnt:  0x00000000
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181078] mmc0: sdhci: Argument:  0x00000000 | Trn mode: 0x00000033
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181085] mmc0: sdhci: Present:   0x1fff0001 | Host ctl: 0x0000001f
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181093] mmc0: sdhci: Power:     0x0000000f | Blk gap:  0x00000000
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181100] mmc0: sdhci: Wake-up:   0x00000000 | Clock:    0x00000007
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181107] mmc0: sdhci: Timeout:   0x0000000a | Int stat: 0x00000000
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181113] mmc0: sdhci: Int enab:  0x02ff008b | Sig enab: 0x02ff008b
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181120] mmc0: sdhci: AC12 err:  0x00000000 | Slot int: 0x00000000
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181131] mmc0: sdhci: Caps:      0x176ec8b0 | Caps_1:   0x03002177
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181138] mmc0: sdhci: Cmd:       0x00000c1a | Max curr: 0x00000000
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181145] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[0]:   0x00000900 | Resp[1]:  0x00000900
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181152] mmc0: sdhci: Resp[2]:   0x00000900 | Resp[3]:  0x00000900
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181157] mmc0: sdhci: Host ctl2: 0x0000800b
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181166] mmc0: sdhci: ADMA Err:  0x00000001 | ADMA Ptr: 0x000000014ee69204
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181169] mmc0: sdhci: ============================================
Aug 28 21:31:52 darkstar kernel: [  617.181757] mmcblk0: error -110 sending stop command, original cmd response 0x0, card status 0x400900
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last mmcblk0 error in your log points very much to a hardware error. I doubt you'll be able to reformat the card.

Comment: OK, so "card dead' hardware, or "card device not properly supported/working" ?  With it being the `mmcblk0` I'm thinking the card, but can you confirm what you were thinking?  Thanks!

Comment: The card is dead for all practical purposes. If its not responding (timeouts) to requests for initialisation/data access its certainly not something that can be worked around in software. So dead.